# Apply perspective matrix order

Tags: javascript, css, matrix, 3d, three.js

I'm actually working on a script `domvertices` which computes the 4 vertices 3d-coordinates of a any DOM element: http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/97a5fb8c1bebacd1958e

```
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
var vertices = domvertices(el);
console.log(vertices);
```

outputs:

```
{
  a: {x: , y: , z: },
  b: {x: , y: , z: },
  c: {x: , y: , z: },
  d: {x: , y: , z: }
}
```

In order to acheive that, I walk the dom up and for each element store the matrix applied to it (cf. ¹).

Finally, I apply the matrices back to the targetted element in the reverse order.

--

Actually it works great!

My only problem is about perspective... For now, I don't take `perspective` nor `perspective-origin` into account when computing element's matrix¹.

As a result, deformation from perspective isn't taken into account(as a workaround when drawing vertices, I append them into the element subjected to perspective so they are correctly positionned).

I'd like to take `perspective` and `perspective-origin` when computing element's matrix.

I can easily make a perpective matrix, my problem is when to apply `perspective` and `perspectiveOrigin` matrix to ¹ ?

What about nested multiple perspective?

¹: Element's matrix  is composed as followed (read right to left):

```
transformOrigin^-1 * transform * transformOrigin * relativePosition * Identity
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/WebGL_model_view_projection

Answer (score 2):

Your perspective matrix needs to be equivalent to being the left-most matrix in the sequence of applied matrices.

e.g. as taken from nearly all WebGL fragment shaders

```
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
```

The projection matrix is on the left.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's kinda very generic and does not really help here... But thx, may be a clue ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a TypeScript library on github which supports perspective transformations and some common transformation methods like **globalToLocal**, **localToGlobal** and **localToLocal**:
jsidea core library.
You can find the matrix-extraction in the [jsidea.geom.Transform.extractMatrix](https://github.com/jsidea/jsidea/blob/master/ts/jsidea/layout/TransformMode/Perspective.ts) function. It looks like that:

```
//subtract transform-origin
matrix.appendPosition(-originX, -originY, -originZ);
//append transform-matrix
matrix.appendCSS(style.transform);
//add transform-origin
matrix.appendPosition(originX, originY, originZ);
//add local position 
//Difficult to calc the local position, 
//because the offsetParent, offsetLeft and offsetTop are not reliable.
matrix.appendPosition(position.x, position.y, 0);
//subtract the perspective-origin
matrix.appendPosition(-perspectiveOriginX, -perspectiveOriginY, 0);
//apply the perspective (aka focalLength)
matrix.appendPerspective(perspective);
//add perspective-origin
matrix.appendPosition(perspectiveOriginX, perspectiveOriginY, 0);
```

Under some conditions the library uses **multiple matrices** for one element.
If the element is in a nested-perspective context and the parent is not preserving 3d (transform-style: flat). You can take a look at the [at this code](https://github.com/jsidea/jsidea/blob/master/ts/jsidea/layout/StyleNode.ts).